# Remove everything between a specific character in a txt file

Tags: python

If I have a .txt file with this content:

```
1020,"Balance",+10000 
1030,"Something",-5000
```

How do I remove whats in the middle, so that the only thing im left with is

```
1020,+10000
1030,-5000
```

Comment: I recommend you learn the basics of Pandas, as it would streamline what you're trying to do (csv and txt file)

Comment: Split on comma and remove middle item. Use regexp to match on the quotes/numbers. Split based on character position e.t.c. There are tons of ways to do this. To find the best way you would need to provide more infromation on how the content of the text-file might vary. Do you for example want to remove all the strings inside quotes? Do you want to remove everything thats not a number? E.t.c. Also provide us with a code-sample or something else describing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

If it's always in the same index:

```py
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    output = []

    for line in lines:
        temp = line.split(",")
        output.append(temp[0])
        output.append(temp[2])
    
   print(output)
```

Comment: That will not work because you will get:
"1020
+10000
1030
-5000" on separate lines.

It should be `output.append(f"{temp[0]},{temp[1]}")`

Comment: Tweaking this a little bit got me the desired result, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it with a regex:

```
import re

string = "1030,\"Something\",-5000"
stripped = re.sub("[\"].*[\"]", "", string)
print stripped
```

This prints `1030,,-5000` from there you can remove one of the commas.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the data into a dataframe using Pandas and then delete the second column like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.txt', header=None)

del df[1]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for this task:

```
import csv

def removeColumn(fn1,fn2,idx=1):
    with open(fn1,"r") as csvfile1:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile1)
        
        with open(fn2,"w") as csvfile2:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile2)
            for row in reader:
                writer.write(row[:idx] + row[:idx+1])
```